# Splitting a string from a potential splitter

Tags: php

It's relatively a common requirement to split a string from a potential splitter:

```
$name = 'John'; // or can be 'John Smith'
```

I use

```
list($firstName, $lastName) = explode(' ', $name) + [1 => null];
```

or

```
@list($firstName, $lastName) = explode(' ', $name);
```

I wonder if you guys use a more concise or more legible method for this?

Comment: You are making the mistake of believing that all names consist of two parts. Take a look at [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) fpr many more gotchas. PHP syntax is the least of your problems

Comment: I use a more traditional way, just `explode` with a `if !empty()`, thanks for sharing this snippets :D

Comment: @Mawg Thanks for your comment. It's just an example. Consider that this is the case for an imaginary application.

Comment: Then I would recommend rewording the question to say something like "what's the canonical way to split a string which always contains two words separated by <insert separator here>" (is the separator always and only a single space)? And, when it comes to names, read that article, plus its siblings about dates,times, addresses, etc, etc

Comment: Deleted my answer, i mis understood the question, would you mind rewriting the question since it is not extremelly clear what you are asking.

Comment: @teeyo check out my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I found it!

```
list($firstName, $lastName) = explode(' ', $name.' ');
```

The simple trick is appending the glue string to the end of the main string. Tadda!

This make accessing to the second part of the string really easy:

```
$domain = explode('@', $filter->email . '@')[1]; // for an invalid input the domain will be ''.
```

Comment: Nice one, you have to check `explode('@', $filter->email . '@')` before trying to access the index **1** to avoid any errors though.

Comment: @teeyo You have not. It's beauty is because you don't have to check. when you have the glue string you will always have the second array item.

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_pop` to get last_name and all in first_name. Your code not works for name which have three words. Example below also works for three words in name like `Niklesh Kumar Raut`

Uncomment one `$name` and comment two to check

```
//$name = "Niklesh";
//$name = "Niklesh Raut";
$name = "Niklesh Kumar Raut";
$name_arr = explode(" ",$name);
$last_name = array_pop($name_arr);
$first_name = implode(" ",$name_arr);
echo "First Name : $first_name\n";//Niklesh Kumar
echo "Last Name : $last_name";//Raut
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/871971

Answer (score -2):

you can use regex to check if the string contains space in between, and then explode using the space to get the first and last string.

```
$name = 'john smith';
$first_name = $name;
$last_name = '';
if(preg_match('/\s/',$name)) {
  list($first_name, $last_name) = explode(' ', $name);
}

echo "Hello ".$first_name."  ".$last_name;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: yeah i agree with that.